# Distribution of different shells

Tags: linux, shell, command

What would be the **command** in linux to find the
distribution of different **shells used by all users**?

Comment: what do you mean by `distribution of different shells` ? Does it mean what shell each user is using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getent passwd | awk -F: '{print $7}' | sort | uniq -c
```

The `getent` command dumps the password database. Normally that's just a file, `/etc/passwd`, but it can come from other sources; using `getent passwd` rather than just reading `/etc/passwd` allows for that.

If your system doesn't have the `getent` command, find out what your system's equivalent is (perhaps `ypcat passwd` if your system uses NIS), or just read the `/etc/passwd` file directly if you're sure the information isn't stored elsewhere.

The `awk` command grabs the 7th colon-delimited field from each line, which is the login shell for that account.

`sort | uniq -c` prints the number of occurrences of each shell. Add `| sort -rn` if you want the list in decreasing order of popularity.

Note carefully that this lists the login shells for *all* accounts on the system, many of which do not actually correspond to users. There are various ways to filter the list (typically the numeric user id, the 3rd field, starts at 1000), but none that are 100% reliable.

Comment: is `getpw` a default content of an OS. I somehow don't have this command in RHEL-5.

Comment: @iamauser: No, it's a custom script that I wrote (and forgot that I had written). I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It usually is just inside `/etc/passwd` (but as the [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18793437/841108) tells, is given by `getent passwd`); on some systems it could by a NIS/YP, LDAP, ... etc ... database (but see also [pam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_PAM)). Details are configurable in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` (see [nsswitch.conf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html) man page).

Also, the authorized login shells are listed in `/etc/shells` (see [shells(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/shells.5.html)); you need to add a shell's pathname there to make it changeable by `chsh` (see [chsh(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chsh.1.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Run this as root !    This will give you the username and their login shell.

```
grep -v "nologin" /etc/passwd | awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{print $1,$7}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could cat out /etc/passwd, awk out the shell field, grep -v out anything you didn't want and then sort unique it.  Like so:

```
cat /etc/passwd | awk -F ":" '{print $7}' | grep -v "whatever" | sort | uniq -c
```

On my mac (which doesn't have any "real" users) this results in

10 with no shell, 1 with /bin/sh, 70 with /usr/bin/false and 1 with /usr/sbin/uucico

Presumably on a system with actual users there'd be /bin/sh, /bin/ksh, /bin/csh and /bin/bash quantities.